# How do i humanize variables like A1+ and A1- (list of blood groups)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do i humanize variables like **A1+** and **A1-** (list of blood groups) to **A1-positive** and **A1-negative**.

Comment: What do you mean humanize "variables?"  Do you actually want to rename variables in your code, or values of strings, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways.

One way i could think of is

```
"A1+".gsub(/[+-]/, "+" => "-positive", "-" => "-negative")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting too much. Ruby or Rails is not an AI, it cannot read your mind. Do it manually.